# Need to change all the hyperlinks in string data to another value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links in a string.

```
var data='<ol>
     <li><a href="#/getpage/getData/1">A Christmas Carol</a></li>
     <li><a href="#/getpage/getData/2">Copyright</a></li>    
     </ol>'
```

Need to change all the links in the string into following format using javascript or jquery.

```
data = '<ol>
  <li><a href="getCurrentPage(1)">A Christmas Carol</a></li>
  <li><a href="getCurrentPage(2)">Copyright</a></li>    
  </ol>'
```

Can anyone help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any notion in RegExp ? It's a powerfull tool that seems to fit your need !

Comment: Dont have idea about them.. Can u help me pls. can we do with RegExp..? the string is a dynamic data coming from server.

Comment: See my proposal below! RegExp are quite simple if you have 2-3 hours left to read some documentation, and you will see it is very powerfull (you should use them everytime you have no simple solution nor performance constraints). You've a good start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var data='<ol><li><a href="#/getpage/getData/1">A Christmas Carol</a></li><li><a href="#/getpage/getData/2">Copyright</a></li></ol>'
var el = $("<div>"+ data + "</div>");
el.find('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('a').attr('href' , "getCurrentPage("+(i+1)+")");
});

data = el.html();
alert(data);
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhRFD/)

For Unsorted strings;

```
var data='<ol><li><a href="#/getpage/getData/1">A Christmas Carol</a></li><li><a href="#/getpage/getData/2">Copyright</a></li></ol>'
var el = $("<div>"+ data + "</div>");
el.find('li').each(function(i) {
    var num = $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace('#/getpage/getData/','');
   $(this).find('a').attr('href' , "getCurrentPage("+ num +")");
});
alert(el.html());
```

Comment: This will work perfectly with good performances if your strings are sorted ("1" appears first in the HTML page, then "2", ...) and if there is no discontinuity. However, if it's not the case, Regex solve the issue with lower performance

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use following script.

```
$("a").each(function(){
  var href=$(this).attr("href");
  $(this).attr("href","getCurrentPage("+href.substring(href.lenght-1,href.length)+")");
});
```

Comment: There will be many other links in the page.. if i try this, others also will get effected. :(

Comment: you can set class of <a> tags to something specific and can use
$(".classname")
all code will be same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
// use Regex to reformat the data
var myregex = new RegExp('<a href="#/getpage/getData/([0-9]+)">', 'g'); // g means "global", i.e. match all
var formated_data = data.replace(myregex, '<a href="getCurrentPage($1)">') // $1 is replaced by the content of the 1st parenthetis of the regex
```

This will find all the "a" tags with a href under the form "#/getpage/getData/" + any integer, and replace them by "a" tags with href under the form "getCurrentPage("+the integer above+")". You can also just match the hrefs without taking into acount the "a" tag.

Comment: If somebody can check my Regex, I didn't use them for long and forgot many special characters that are to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href^="#/getpage/getData/"]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var id = href.replace('#/getpage/getData/','');
    $(this).attr('href', 'getCurrentPage(' + id + ')');
});
```

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsWMj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have already found a solution. Just that I spend sometime on this, I want to share my solution. I won't mind if you don't agree with my solution. I'll definitely appreciate if you just have a look at the solution.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ARPzA/

```
$('body').append('<div/>').find('div:last').addClass('temp');
$('.temp').html(data);
$('.temp a[href^="#/getpage/getData/"]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var id = href.replace('#/getpage/getData/','');
    $(this).attr('href', 'getCurrentPage(' + id + ')');
});

data=$('.temp').html();

$('.temp').text(data);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

use replace function of javascript ,http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: We don know the current string, its a dynamic one...:(

Comment: oh , then its difficult to even predict the target string ,use regexp